# How to set up Exoplayer with dash streaming?

Tags: android, video-streaming, mp4, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

Can anyone please help me by giving me a working sample of the implementation of Exoplayer with DASH streaming for mp4 file from URL. I am totally lost and tired of trying tutorials and stack-overflow questions for 2 days to implement this feature.

From the tutorials I followed, some of them were mentioning keywords such as manifest file, mpd format, DASH manifest and so on. I am really really lost with all these keywords and staffs related to them. Can any one take me out of this swamp please.

Note: please do not provide me with tutorials or stack-overflow past questions as I have checked all of them but still helpless.

Comment: I think part of the problem is your misunderstanding of what DASH is. You are asking about playing an mp4 file with DASH but that does not make sense. You can convert an mp4 to dash format with a tool like ffmpeg, that will create a dash manifest (.mpd) you can play.

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct about where I am misunderstanding. Can send me a link please on a tutorial or example that teaches how can I do so(convert MP4 to dash format) on android.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to split your mp4 file into dash chunks. Have you done it?

Comment: No, actually that's the point where I am stuck, I don't know how to do that, can you please let me know how to do it?

Comment: you need either to segment it with ffmpeg, either use streaming server that will do it on fly: flussonic, wowza or what is there.